# change the position of a LinearLayout to the footer of the screen

Tags: android, xml

I am new in android and I have problem in putting the red linearLayout as a footer in my screen,this is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android           =   "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id              =   "@+id/mainWidgetContainer"
    android:layout_width    =   "match_parent"
    android:layout_height   =   "match_parent"
    android:background      =   "@color/blue"
    android:orientation     =   "vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/....." >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/languageButton"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical=  "true"
                android:visibility          =   "gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


   <!-- to add the footer here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id              =   "@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width    =   "match_parent"
        android:layout_height   =   "45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the result that I get:

[image]

so please any help,how can I make the red LinearLayout in the footer of the screen,I have used `android:gravity="bottom"` and this not working

thanks for help

Update:
this is what I get when applying Sir Lovekush Vishwakarma solution:
[image]

the white bar is gone

this is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android           =   "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id              =   "@+id/mainWidgetContainer"
    android:layout_width    =   "match_parent"
    android:layout_height   =   "match_parent"
    android:background      =   "@color/blue"
    android:orientation     =   "vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.ofss.fcdb.mobile.android.phone.aman.launcher" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/languageButton"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="27dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!--     to add the footer here -->
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>   

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: change  main LinearLayout to RelativeLayout and add line in child LinearLayout  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".

Comment: so we your updated xml, you missing something.

Comment: I have put my updated code Sir

Answer (score 3):

use like this, i have change LinearLayout to RelativeLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/....."
    android:id="@+id/mainWidgetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/languageButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- to add the footer here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

if you want to do it only by LinearLayout than use this below code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainWidgetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/languageButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- to add the footer here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your help but I have a problem when applying the code I think it comes from the parent RelativeLayout when I change it the a LinearLayout the error is gone but back to the original problem with the footer :(

Comment: thanks again Sir for help,but when applying your code this is what I get as a result (update for my post)

Answer (score 1):

Use below XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainWidgetContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/languageButton"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- to add the footer here -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: thanks Sir for your help but I have a problem when applying the code I think it comes from the parent RelativeLayout when I change it the a LinearLayout the error is gone but back to the original problem with the footer :(

Comment: means you have change Relative Layout to LinearLayout

Comment: yes Sir but with that I have back to the original problem with the footer

Comment: Yes Thats why i have added Relative Layout because , In Linear Layout there is no Relative property  .